# I can't figure out why this javascript code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I was making a function to change an element's text. It runs without throwing an error, but it doesn't do anything when I call the function.

```
var randomFunction = {
  text: function(element, text) {
    var slice = element.length;
    switch (element.charAt(0)) {
      case "#":
        var splice = element.slice(1, slice - 1);
        document.getElementById(splice).innerHTML = text;
        break;
      case ".":
        var splice = element.slice(1, slice - 1);
        document.getElementById(splice).innerHTML = text;
        break;
      default:
        document.getElementsByTagName(element).innerHTML = text;
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

// Usage: randomFunction.text("div", "Hello World");

Comment: Those are some very, very confusing variable names. Consider using variable names more representative of what they contain.

Comment: Did you mean `getElementsByClassName` in the `"."` case? Why not just use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

Comment: Note that you can `.slice(1, -1)` instead of explicitly referencing the length (but you probably just want `.slice(1)`).

Answer (score -1):

Getelementsbytagname results would be an array. Iterate over it and set the innerhtml property.

Comment: So vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: No, it is *not* an array.

Comment: Why the downvote